# What is the life story and miracles associated with kanakadasa?

Tags: krishna, life, bhakti, saint

Kanaka dasa was a poet saint hailing from Karnataka region.

He belonged to the bhakti sampradaya and composed many devotional songs and kirtans especially on lord Krishna

It is also said that some miracles happened which were especially related to uDupi Krishna temple.

What was his life story?

What were the miracles associated with him?